# Module 'google maps' not found after adding another dependency on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have been working with googles map SDK and I haven't had any problems until I added another dependency in my podfile. I get this error in Xcode saying, "Module 'Google Maps' not found" where I have '@import GoogleMaps'. If I take out the new pod the error goes away and everything works fine. I just recently started using cocoaPods, Is there something I'm missing in my podfile?

```
platform :ios, '6.1'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

Comment: you do it? make sure you completed the steps needed to add dependency in your pod. Try to follow the instruction listed here: https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods#add_a_google_sdk_to_your_ios_app

Comment: did all that multiply times and still doesn't seem to work. @d.datul1990 the code i have is with out the platform :ios '8.1' which still works if its the only dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add

```
 target 'Your Project' do

  pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'

  pod 'GoogleMaps'

  target 'Your ProjectTests' do

    # Pods for testing


  end
```

The project will run fine now..