# How to resolve error- module of GoogleMap not found ? using cocoa pods

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, frameworks, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

[image]platform :ios, ‘7.0’

target 'ConsumerApp' do

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
end    
target 'ConsumerAppTests' do    
end
```

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580829/module-google-maps-not-found-after-adding-another-dependency-on-xcode) if it can help you.

Comment: i had tried but not working, error i got same as earlier.. KENdi